# Display uploaded PDF in embedded link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

Am trying to upload and Preview a pdf document, here my code:

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <input name="file" type="file" id="btnupload" />
   <input type="button" value="Preview" id="btnPrvw"  />
</div>
<embed width="575" height="500" id="embdLink"/>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var filename;
   $('#btnupload').change(function () {
      if (this.files[0].name != "") {
          filename = $('#btnupload').val();
      }
   });
   $('#btnPrvw').click(function () {                  
      $('#embdLink').data = filename;
   });
});
```

but it is not displaying anything, what am doing wrong?expecting great suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved this issue by applying the following script. thanks for those who works on this question: here is the solution:

```
 <script>
        var srcContent;
        function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    srcContent=  e.target.result;
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }       
        $(document).ready(function () {        
            $("#inputFile").change(function () {
                if (this.files[0].name != "") {
                    readURL(this);                  
                }                    
            });    
            $('#btnPrvw').click(function () {              
                $('#embdLink').attr('src', srcContent);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.files` object , `Blob` , `URL.createObjectURL()` , selecting `DOM` element `[0]` property `src` at `$('#embdLink')[0].src`

html

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" id="embdLink" />
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var filename;
  $('#btnupload').change(function() {
    if (this.files[0].name != "") {
      filename = this.files[0]
    }
  });
  $('#btnPrvw').click(function() {
    $('#embdLink')[0].src = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([filename], {"type":"application/pdf"}));
  });
});
```